# switch statement and incrementation operator

Tags: c++, switch-statement, post-increment

I wrote the following code:

```
int i = 0;  
switch(i++)  
{
   case 0:  
     cout << 0;  
   case 1:  
     cout << 1;
}  
cout << "\n" << i;
```

The output of the code was like this:

```
01  
1
```

Can anyone please explain the first line of output? Why are 0 and 1 both being printed?

Comment: Greatest Design Flaw in any language: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/55047/what-is-the-greatest-design-flaw-you-have-faced-in-any-programming-language/55128#55128 `switch` rated the first position for this stupid (and error prone) behavior.

Answer (score 18):

First, the expression `i++` (*post-increment operator*) evaluates to 0 (even though it sets the value of `i` to 1). So inside the `switch`, the `case 0:` branch is selected.

Then, because there is no `break` after your `case 0:`, the program continues with executing the code in the `case 1:` label.

Summing it up, you have: 0 from the first `switch` branch, 1 from the second branch, and another 1 because that's the final value of `i`.

Answer (score 7):

Because you need to add a `break` after each case, which prevents execution of the following statements. E.g.

```
switch(i++)  
{
   case 0:  
     cout<<0;  
     break;
   case 1:  
     cout<<1;
     break;
}
```

Admittedly, the second break is superfluous but I put it there just for the sake of consistency

Comment: Do you not typically indent the `break` to line up with the block of statements in the `case` branch? That looks strange to me.

Comment: Yes, but formatting code can be kind of tedious on SO. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put "break;" at the end of each case.

Answer (score 0):

switch is a strange construct. It comes from C, and Java and C# adopted it too, so it is not considered totally "non-OO".

switch on state which changes is a valid OO concept, but often is used for switching based on type.

In particular the compiler usually creates a "jump" table which means it is O(1) what block of code gets called, unlike a nested "if" statement. You may have multiple values (not including default) jump to the same point, thus code blocks "run into" each other unless you explicitly insert a "break" statement.

This is how it was done in C and has been retained for C++.

With regards to the value in the switch, it must be a numeric value but does not have to be a constant. In your case `i++` evaluates to 0 but increments i to 1. This is well-defined behaviour and there is no issues with sequence points here.

Comment: it is a postincrement operator, right. so,it will get incremented after doing its job in the expression of which it is a part....so is it like after it has printed 0, it increments itself and then goes to case 1